# How to use custom font without size?

Tags: ios

I want to use a custom font in whole app (ios 5). I used the following code

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:17.0]];
```

The problem with this is that it overrides all font sizes in all views.

How can i avoid it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create category for UILabel and add the following code over there.

```
@implementation UILabel (CustomFontLabel)

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    float size = [self.font pointSize];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:size];
}

@end
```